# mysqli prepare returns false but SQL is valid

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm using the prepare function from mysqli to create a query to my database but it fails on me even when I have many request working earlier in the same page.

My query looks like this :

```
if ($insert = $mysqli->prepare( "INSERT INTO table_name (id_user, token) VALUES (?, ?)")) {
    // Do some cool stuff here
} else {
    var_dump($mysqli->error);
    var_dump($insert->error);
}
```

During the execution, it goes into the else and the output is :

```
string(0) "" //var_dump($mysqli->error);
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in // var_dump($insert->error);
```

I know that my $mysqli is working so I also tested out these strings inside the prepare statement. None of them worked ether. (I tested them in mysql/phpmyadmin and they work fine)

```
"INSERT INTO `table_name` (`id_user`, `token`) VALUES (?, ?)"
"INSERT INTO `table_name` (`table_name`.`id_user`, `table_name`.`token`) VALUES (?, ?)"
'INSERT INTO `table_name` (`id_user`, `token`) VALUES (50, "random_token")'
```

Can someone help me with this little headache?

Thanks

Comment: Possibly some kind of connection error.

Comment: Where does the part about `bind_param` come in?

Comment: @Fred-ii- In the *"Do some cool stuff here"* section, I'd imagine

Comment: @Phil *That's* what I kinda figured.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it's exactly the first line in the "_Do some cool stuff here_"

Comment: @K-Jtan I missed the mark - someone else seems to have found the problem. I've deleted my comment

Comment: @MikeW In fact, the problem still exists when I remove completely the else statement. I just posted the output so you could see I tested out that path.

Comment: mysqli_prepare() returns a statement object or FALSE if an error occurred

Answer (score 1):

The error is actually complaining about $insert not being defined... Which makes sense, as it's hitting your else statement.

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in // var_dump($insert->error);
```

Notice the error you yourself commented, and what it's actually complaining about. You shouldn't be referencing the $insert variable in the else statement

Comment: This answers the question but it's odd that `$mysqli->error` doesn't show any value

Comment: I know that the $insert is not define. I believe it's not define since the prepare function returns bool(false). What I want to know is why is _prepare_ returning false :-S

Answer (score -1):

I finally figured it out. The problem is that I didn't closed my previous connections. One of them was already using the same name *$insert*

Two possible fixes I found for someone who could find this thread.

Fix 1 - **CLOSE YOUR CONNECTIONS**, it's as simple has

```
$connectionVariable->close();
```

Fix 2 - Name your variables differently. Although you should always do the Fix 1 first. I guess I had to find it the hard way.

P.S. Thanks to everyone who helped me

Comment: the only fix you actually need is proper error reporting.